# Call javascript method defined in parent from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

After some research (even at stackoverflow) I still can't figure out how to do this. `parent.method()` won't do the trick, nor some other solutions I've tried.

**Situation:** I have a *index.html* on the client side (mobile phone in this case) which has an iframe loading server-side page. What I need to do is call a javascript method defined in the *index.html* (client side) from the iframe content (server-side).

As an example (I'm not using android in the question described above), Android apps have `addJavascriptInterface` which, when defined, allows one to call methods defined client-side from server-side pages just invoking `window.CustomObject.MethodToCall()`.

Any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: try `top` instead of `parent` and check you are definitely not doing x-domain or x-protocol.

Comment: Are the parent frame and the iframe on the same domain?

Comment: top also doesn't do the trick. Since the index.html is defined client-side, I believe it could be seen as different domains. But if this is the case, and therefore not possible to call the js method, how can we explain the android example I gave above? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by index.html is defined client side? That's kind of nonsensical.

Comment: Imagine a mobile app that's composed by an index.html and that has an iframe inside, loading contents. It's opened by a 'contained' browser, just like an app (more or less like phonegap does, just to give an example).

Comment: annakata: do you want me to explain a little further? 
NullUserException: they're not in the same domain because the parent frame is located at the mobile phone (index.html located at mobile phone) and contains an iframe pointing to a url that I control

Answer (score 1):

```
window.top.foo
```

for the top level window

```
window.parent.foo
```

for the direct parent

Answer (score 1):

I realize I am only a year late to this party but there was no real answer.

So, in order to do this both files must be on the same domain. Since you have the index.html on the phones localhost and load a page on your site it will not work (locahost to example.com). You could load the index.html off your site as well and that would fix this problem (example.com to example.com). Then you could reference the parent frame in the normal `window.top.function`.

Answer (score 1):

In certain situation there could be a neccessity of calling a javascript function inside an iframe from the parent document, and vice versa ie;
calling a javascript function in parent document from the iframe.

**For example;** the parent document have an iframe with id attribute ‘iFrameId‘, and the function ‘functionInIframe()‘ is defined in that iframe document.
Following code can call that iframe function from the parent document itself.

```
document.getElementById('iFrameId').contentWindow.functionInIframe();
```

And following code can call the function defined in parent document(functionInParent()) from the iframe itself.

```
parent.functionInParent();
```

This way javascript can interact between parent document and iframe.

This is the [original post](http://www.holmescreation.com/2012/03/calling-javascript-function-defined-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-document/).